# Polynomial Multiplication in GF(256)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

I would like to compute the following:

```
10100011 * 01100011 in GF(256) using the AES irreducible polynomial.
```

So first we get the polynomials:

```
10100011 = x^8 + x^6 + x + 1
01100011 = x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + 1
```

Multiplying these out, I got the result:

```
x^56 + x^48 + x^42 + x^36 + x^16 + x^12 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
```

So when I try to reduce this using the AES irreducible polynomial, x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1, I am getting the result:

```
 x^7 + x^6 with a remainder of x^42 + x^36 + x^28 + x^24  +x^21 + x^18 + x^16 + x^12 + x^8 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
```

This cannot be correct, but I'm having trouble finding where I made a mistake. I have a feeling my multiplication of the two polynomials is incorrect.

Comment: $x^7x^8 = x^{15}$, not $x^{56}$ ...

Comment: Argh, I knew that... what a dumb mistake, I've been working with numbers for too long I need a break haha. Thank you @Thomas

Answer (score 2):

The exponentiation law is:

$x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$